# How do I delete all lines with ".png" in a file?

Tags: sed, tr

I've a list of urls of which some point to images:

```
http://s.thebrighttag.com/iframe?c=A5lqOqP
http://s.wordpress.com/imgpress?resize=136,136&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.whicdn.com%2Fimages%2F2833524%2F4thofJuly-collage_large.jpg%3F1278084193
```

How do I remove those lines from the file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
cat file | grep -v "\.png" >new_file_without_pngs
```

Updated for comment:

```
egrep -iv "\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|etc)" file >new_file
```

Comment: no inline option? I'd like to get rid of ".png" and ".jpg" for that matter. Also case-insenstive?

Comment: I would add a `$` at end, just in case.

Answer (score 6):

For the in-place editing variant, you can use `sed` like the following:

```
$ sed -i -r 's/.*\.(png|jpg).*//I' file
```

It will remove the lines containing either `.png` or `.jpg` directly in the file. The `-i` option passed to `sed` means 'in-place editing'. Make a backup of your file before executing this command, or try it first without the `-i` option if you are unsure.

The `I` flag is to perform a case-insensitive matching.

Comment: How about using the sed delete command 'd': sed -i -r '/\.(png|jpg)$/I d' file

Comment: you can add an extension to -i so that it will create a backup file:
sed -i .bak -r 's/.*\.(png|jpg).*//I' file

Comment: +1 to the "use `d`" comment: using `s/.*blah.*//` will leave blank lines, it won't delete lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'g/\.png/d' -cx file
```

1. `g` global search
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score 0):

If you have [`sponge`](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/) you can swap out the contents of a file in place like this:

```
grep -E -iv "\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)" file | sponge file
```